# How to hide my mailing address in Chrome Store?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I created my first Chrome Store app and submitted it for review. I was forced to provide my street mailing address and on previewing my app in the Chrome Store it shows my mailing address to the world. I am not too happy about that. Is there any way NOT to have my mailing address on the Chrome Store? I am not a business, just an individual. It worries my that some nut job might show up at my house, or mail me some hate mail.

Comment: have you already tried to provide a new street mailing address like "666 damn google street"? However, the last time I updated an extension, I was not asked to provide any addresses

Comment: At first I put in my complete address but then when I saw a preview of my extension how it would appear it showed my full address so I edited it and removed the house number and just left my street name, city, state, zip. Now I can not even find where to edit my address; I mean what if I moved and needed to put in a new address? I hope when I update my extension that I can not put in an address.

Comment: Try to ask here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions